# Django: Display NullBooleanField as Radio and default to None

Tags: python, django, forms, form-fields

I am successfully implementing `NullBooleanField` as radio buttons in several ways but the problem is that I can not set the default value to None.

Here is the code:

```
models.py:
class ClinicalData(models.Model):
      approved = models.NullBooleanField()
      ...

forms.py:
NA_YES_NO = ((None, 'N/A'), (True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No'))
class ClinicalDataForm(ModelForm):
      approved = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=NA_YES_NO))
      class Meta:
           model = ClinicalData
```

I tried the following methods:
Set `default:None` in the model and/or setting `inital:None` in the form and also in the view in the form instance. 
None of that was successfull. Im currently using `CharField` instead of `NullBooleanField`. 
 But is there some way to get this results with `NullBooleanField`???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some odd reason - I didn't check it at the Django code -, as soon as you provide a custom widget for a NullBooleanField, it doesn't accept the values you expect (`None`, `True` or `False`) anymore.

By analyzing the built-in choices attribute, I found out that those values are equal to, respectively, `1`, `2` and `3`.

So, this is the quick-and-dirty solution I fould to stick to radio buttons with 'Unknown' as default:

```
class ClinicalDataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ClinicalData

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ClinicalDataForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        approved = self.fields['approved']
        approved.widget = forms.RadioSelect(
            choices=approved.widget.choices)
        approved.initial = '1'
```

It doesn't look good and I wouldn't use it unless very necessary. But there it is, just in case.

Answer (score 8):

I know this has been answered for a while now, but I was also trying to solve this problem and came across this question.

After trying emyller's solution, it seemed to work, however when I looked at the form's `self.cleaned_data`, I saw that the values I got back were all either `True` or `None`, no `False` values were recorded.

I looked into the Django code and saw that while the normal NullBooleanField select does indeed map `None`, `True`, `False` to `1`, `2`, `3` respectively, the RadioSelect maps `1` to `True`, `0` to `False` and any other value to `None`

This is what I ended up using:

```
my_radio_select = forms.NullBooleanField(
    required=False,
    widget=widgets.RadioSelect(choices=[(1, 'Yes'), (0, 'No'), (2, 'N/A')]),
    initial=2,  # Set initial to 'N/A'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, the other answers given here no longer apply in Django 1.7. Setting `choices` to `[(True, "Yes"), (False, "No"), (None, "N/A")]` works just fine.

Comment: To make it work, I had to wrap None with quotes like this ('None', 'N/A').

Answer (score 1):

For me in Django 1.7 None value is not selected by default (despite what Craig claims). I subclassed RadioSelect, it helped in my case:

```
from django.forms.widgets import RadioSelect
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy

class NullBooleanRadioSelect(RadioSelect):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        choices = (
            (None, ugettext_lazy('Unknown')),
            (True, ugettext_lazy('Yes')),
            (False, ugettext_lazy('No'))
        )
        super(NullBooleanRadioSelect, self).__init__(choices=choices, *args, **kwargs)

    _empty_value = None
```

Answer (score 1):

I've achieved this with Django 2.2.

You should be able to have the `None` radio option checked with a `ChoiceField` and `RadioSelect` widget. The trick is to set the `None` choice value to empty string `''`.

The model field I used was a `BooleanField` with `null=True` which is essentially the same as the model field `NullBooleanField`.

```
approved = forms.ChoiceField(
    choices=[(True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No'), ('', 'N/A')],
    widget=forms.RadioSelect,
    required=False,
)
```